# Emacs simple arithmetics in query replace

Tags: emacs, regular-expression, replace, arithmetic

Is it possible to do the following in `emacs`:

Query replace all numbers in a region by the number +n, for example if you have:

```
12 and 7 are nice numbers
```

let n be 3, then it should transform to

```
15 and 10 are nice numbers
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, `\&` can be used in replace expression to represent the entire match, similarly `\#&` can be used to represent the entire match as number.

More concretely:

M-x query-replace-regexp `\b[0-9]+\b` RETURN `\,(+ 3 \#&)`

And a quote from [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html)

> You can use Lisp expressions to calculate parts of the replacement
>   string. To do this, write ‘\,’ followed by the expression in the
>   replacement string. Each replacement calculates the value of the
>   expression and converts it to text without quoting.